# Convert readFile csv to string to parse

Tags: javascript, node.js

Ran .readFile(filePath) on a csv in node.js. After converting response to string I get back something like.

```
header1, header2, header3
item1, item2, item3
item4, item5, item6
```

and in order to parse it I need to convert it in this format.

```
  "header1","header2","header3"
  "item1","item2","item3"
  "item4","item5","item6"
```

I'm using csv-parse and not sure how to go about this 
https://csv.js.org/parse/info/

Comment: CSV files do not require `"` for every field - so, you're either misunderstanding something, or the library your using is rubbish

Answer (score 0):

CSV only needs quote marks around fields when those fields contain characters that would otherwise confound CSV: stuff like commas and new lines.

Just parse your string data. If it doesn’t work please ask another question, and show the code that uses the ‘csv‘ package.